# Using Naive Bayes classifier for unsupervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, naive-bayes, expectation-maximization, unsupervised-learning

I was going through [this](http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_255.html) article to learn about how the EM algorithm can be used to use the Naive Bayes algorithm for unsupervised learning. Suppose we have the following data without labels:

1 0 1 1

0 1 1 0

0 0 1 1

We want to make 3 clusters out of them, and for a new vector x, find P(C = c | x). Now, as they suggest, we set out with assigning each vector in the training data to a class with some random probability (count). For example:

1 0 1 1 cluster = 1 count = 0.4

1 0 1 1 cluster = 2 count = 0.4

1 0 1 1 cluster = 3 count = 0.2

....

....

Now, they use the EM algorithm to update the count values, and estimate P(C), P($X_j$|C) using those values. Can someone explain to me how they are doing it? I can't comprehend the abstract language used in the article. Thanks!

Comment: The described model to me looks like Bernoulli mixture model (suggest to find references on BMM). The idea is to define a cluster as a collection of Bernoulli variables that are cluster-specific. I have the Bayesian version of this model implemented in Infer.NET.

Answer (score 1):

A [nice Python implementation of Naive Bayes Clustering](https://github.com/mruffini/NaiveBayesClustering) combining EM algorithm and Naive Bayes algorithm for unsupervised learning.

This implementation based on « heuristic » approximate method of moments (MOM) and tensor decomposition techniques was used to cluster high-dimensional binary data patients in groups from their electronic healthcare records. The [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v68/ruffini17a/ruffini17a.pdf) « Clustering Patients with Tensor Decomposition » in Proceedings of Machine Learning for Healthcare 2017 gives detailed explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).